# How to store referenced subdocument in typegraphql with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, typeorm, typegraphql

I having a collection name Shop and another is members. I want store data in collection shop
with structure as:

```
@ObjectType('ShopType')
@InputType('ShopInput')
@Entity()
 class Shop{

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @prop({ unique: true, required: true })
    public id!: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @prop({ unique: false, required: true })
    public name!: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @prop({ unique: true, required: true })
    public logo_url!: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @prop({ unique: true, required: true })
    public registration_no!: string;

    @Field(type => [Memeber], { nullable: true })
    @prop({
    unique: false, required: false, ref: () => [Memeber],
    type: () => [Schema.Types.Mixed].  // Taken from package mongoose
     })
    public members?: Ref<Memeber>[];

   }
```

Same as for Member collection

**But I'm Getting Error**:

> Shop validation failed: memebers.0: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Document {\n  id: >'emp1.1',\n  category: 'waiter
> ',\n  name:'3',\n  joining_date: 1600279449 }" at path "memebers", > members: '3',\n  joining_date: 1600279449 }" at path "memebers", members:
> Cast to Array failed for value "[ Member {\n    id: 'emp1.1',\n
> category: 'waiter',\n    owner_id: '3',\n    joining_date: 1600279449 }
> ]" at path "members""

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this issue got resolved by me as I was mainly focusing on using typeorm to do this job but it is type goose which creating the Models.
Here below code for reference to the solution: -

> For Model Company(Parent Doc)

```
   import { getModelForClass, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
   @ObjectType('CompanyType')
   @InputType('CompanyInput')
   @Entity('company')
   class Company{
   @Field(() => [Company] || null, { nullable: true })
   @prop({
          unique: false, required: false,
          autocomplete: true,
          default: [], ref: 'Branch'
         })
         public branches?: Ref<Branch>[];
        
     }
```

> For Model Branch(reference subdoc)

```
   import { getModelForClass, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
   @ObjectType('BranchType')
   @InputType('BranchInput')
   @Entity('branch')
   class Branch{
        @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
        @prop({
                unique: false, required: false,
            })
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
        public id: number;
    }
```

Above "ref" is  and never do ref: () => Model or ref: Model.
Also above code is the example of reference subdocuments in MongoDB which will give a result on create() or insertMany() as:-

```
{
branches: [ObjectId("Some pattern"),...]

}
```

Here ObjectId's are reference Id or ObjectId(_id) which is unique for every document in a collection.
For more info refer https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/ and for ORM https://typeorm.io/#/